# How to make psd image in html

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on project where in final result, I need to have like this

[image: final result I should have]

As you can see in modal, there is background-image and 2 icons, my problem is I don't know how to make it,

I did a div with image background but for icons I have them in psb format and I don't know how to put them on the background in beautiful way .

I tried to screen part of icon and put it but it wasn't good

```
<section id="about">
      <div class="container-fluid mt-0" style="background-image: url(background.png);background-size:cover;height:550px">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
            <h2 class="section-heading mt-5">Nos activités</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row text-center" >
          <div class="col-md-6 image"  >
            <img src="icon1.png">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6" style="padding-top: 100px">
            <img src="icon2.png">

          </div>
        </div>
        <!--
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
            <h2 class="section-heading ">Nos dernières réalisataions</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>-->
    </section>
```

[image: This is what I am able to do, as you can see there is kind of limit in icons]

Comment: Please tag your Bootstrap version.

Comment: PSD files aren't images. They're Photoshop data files. You mention them several times. Are we actually talking about PNG files?

Answer (score 0):

This is the structure I'm doing - just replace the images and add the font type

```css
.activities {
    background-image: url('http://inspirationhut.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/61.png');
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
}
.activities .title {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 25px 0;
    color: #5ABF28;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.activities .row {
    min-height: calc(100vh - 135px);
    align-items: center;
}
.activities .activity {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 10px auto;
}
.activities .activity p {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #999;
}
.activities .activity button {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 0;
    border-radius: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    outline: 0;
    background: none;
    border: 2px solid #aaa;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #999;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.activities .activity:hover p,
.activities .activity:hover button {
    color: #5ABF28;
    border-color: #5ABF28;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="activities text-center">
    <div class="container">
        <h2 class="title pt-5">Nos activités</h2>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm">
                
                <a href="#" class="activity">
                    <img src="https://www.ikea.com/in/en/images/products/smycka-artificial-flower__0903311_PE596728_S5.JPG?f=s" alt="icon 1" height="120" />
                    <p class="text-uppercase mt-3">entretien de jardin</p>
                    <button>...</button>
                </a>
                
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm">
                
                <a href="#" class="activity">
                    <img src="https://www.ikea.com/us/en/images/products/smycka-artificial-flower-rose-white__0903190_PE596774_S5.JPG" alt="icon 1" height="120" />
                    <p class="text-uppercase mt-3">creation de jardin</p>
                    <button>...</button>
                </a>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```